# How to parse then paste in the same line in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file like this `A.txt` (field separator = `,`) :

```
Kit Batch Export
Software Version = NO_v1
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = Cji
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Nov
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis,EC,CH
,novaprime-ct044032-TB_2034,2061571293,A01,Unkn-01,VALID,,,
,novaprime-ct044032-TB_2034,2061584371,A02,Unkn-09,VALID,,,
```

And `B.csv` (field separator = `\t` ; first column is empty ) :

```
    Well    Fluor   Target  Content Sample  Cq  SQ
    A01 Cy5 EC  Unkn-01 2060563935  26  NaN
    A02 Cy5 CH  Unkn-09 2060565055  37  NaN
    A01 Cy5 CH  Unkn-01 2060565888  54  NaN
    A02 Cy5 EC  Unkn-09 2060565465  NaN NaN
```

And I want to add the value (column Cq) of each line for Well/Target (example here : A01/EC; A01/CH; A02/EC; A02/CH)  of `B.txt` in the corresponding line/column of `A.txt` like this :

```
Kit Batch Export
Software Version = NO_v1
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = Cji
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Nov
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis,EC,CH
,novaprime-ct044032-TB_2034,2061571293,A01,Unkn-01,VALID,,,,26,54
,novaprime-ct044032-TB_2034,2061584371,A02,Unkn-09,VALID,,,,NaN,37
```

To do that I try that :

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{if (a[$2]) {a[$2]=a[$2] "," $7} else {a[$2]=$7}} NR>FNR{split($0,f,","); if (a[f[4]]) $0=$0 "," a[f[4]]; print}' B.txt A.txt > C.txt
```

It kinda works but it paste the value when it encounter the first iteration, not when it recognise if it's EC or CH. So do you have a different method to properly do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work as long as no comma can appear in the "Header" lines:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR{if ($4=="EC") ec[$2]=$7; else if ($4=="CH") ch[$2]=$7; next}
            NR>FNR&&NF>1 {if (!f) f=1; else {$10=ec[$4]; $11=ch[$4];}}1' B.txt FS=',' OFS=',' A.txt
```

This will first parse `B.txt` and create an "EC-to-Well"-map and a "CH-to-Well"-map, which is then used when parsing `A.txt`. We set the field separators to `,` for `A.txt` and ensure we only process lines with more than one field (i.e. at least one `,`), but not the first one which contains the column titles.

**Update**

Since you state in a comment that sometimes `B.txt` can contain empty fields where you want to ensure they are replaced with `NaN`, we need an additional check:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR{if ($4=="EC") ec[$2]=$7; else if ($4=="CH") ch[$2]=$7; next}
            NR>FNR&&NF>1 {if (!f) f=1; else {$10=ec[$4]?ec[$4]:"NaN"; $11=ch[$4]?ch[$4]:"NaN";}}1' B.txt FS=',' OFS=',' A.txt
```

This is very "golfed", but basically

```
$10=ec[$4] ? ec[$4] : "NaN"
```

means

```
if (ec[$4]) $10=ec[$4]; else $10="NaN"
```

Comment: @nstatam You're welcome. If you ever encounter a situation where `,` can occur in the "header" lines, you could try to modify the `NF>1` condition to something like `$0 !~ /.*=.*/` to explicitly exclude all lines containing a `=`.

Comment: Hi, sorry to re-open this issue but I wich to add something to this command; If the value of what I have to paste is empty, I want to replace it by `NaN`. Do you have a clue how to change your previous solution ? Thanks

Comment: @nstatam Added instructions and explanations

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full explication !